# PHP email form not sending email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Can anyone help me figure out why this email form won't send an email? I've checked with IT and they said that the email function the server it's on is turned on and other websites being hosted can send emails. The form is pulling the data... it just won't send the email. I feel like it's going to be something really obvious that's causing the email to not send and I just can't see it.

```
<?php 
    require 'topInclude.php';
?>
<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="waiverContent">
    <div id="dvdContentRight">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var defaultMessage = "Please provide a brief description of how you plan to adapt the messaging and/or graphic design.";
            $("#myTextArea").focus(function(){
                if( $(this).val() == defaultMessage){
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            }).blur(function(){
                if( $(this).val() == "" ){
                    $(this).val(defaultMessage);
                }
            }).val(defaultMessage);
        });
    </script>

<?php       
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$errors = array(); // Initialize the errors array

if (empty($_POST['company_name'])) {
     $errors[] = 'Please enter your first name.';
} else {
      $Cn = filter_var($_POST['company_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
}

if (empty($_POST['contact_name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter your name.';
} else {
    $ln = filter_var($_POST['contact_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
}

if (empty($_POST['address'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter your work address.';
} else {
    $add = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
}

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter your email address.';
} else {
    $e = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
}

if (empty($_POST['comments']) || ($_POST['comments'] == 'Please provide a brief description of how you plan to adapt the messaging and/or graphic design.')) {
    $errors[] = 'Please provide a brief description of how you plan to adapt the messaging and/or graphic design.';
} else {
    $co = filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
}

if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    $p = $_POST['phone'];
} else {
    $p = '';
}

if (empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You must agree to the Permission To Use / Reproduce conditions.';
} else {
    $cb = $_POST['checkbox'];
}

    if (empty($errors)) { 
        $body = "The information sent is as follows:\n\n Company Name: $Cn \n Contact Name: $ln \n Work Address: $add \n Phone: $p \n Email: $e \n I agree to terms: $cb \n\n Comments: $co"; 
        mail ('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'W.E. Can Quit DVD Request', $body, 'From: '.$e);

        echo '<div id="email"><div id="emailSent">
                <h1>Thank you!</h1>
                <p>Your request has been sent.</p>
              </div>';
        echo '<div id="emailSentImg"><img src="images/emailSent.jpg" /></div></div>';

    } else { //Report any collected errors in the errors array.
        echo '<div id="emailNotSent">
            <h1>Error!</h1><br />
            <p>The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
            foreach ($errors as $msg) {
                echo " - $msg<br />\n";
            }
        echo '</p><br /><p>Please use the \'back\' button in your browser and try again.</p>
              </div>';

    } // Ends the empty errors array if.

    } else { // Form has not been submitted; display the form.
    $errors = NULL; 
?>
```

Here is the email form:

```
<h2>Order Your DVD</h2>
        <div id="dvdForm">
            <form name="form" id="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
            <table width="550px">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="company_name" class="formText">Company Name:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input  type="text" name="company_name" maxlength="50" size="45" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['company_name'])) echo $_POST['company_name']; ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="contact_name" class="formText">Contact Name:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input  type="text" name="contact_name" maxlength="50" size="45" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['contact_name'])) echo $_POST['contact_name']; ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="address" class="formText">Work Address:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input  type="text" name="address" maxlength="50" size="45" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['address'])) echo $_POST['address']; ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="phone" class="formText">Phone Number:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input  type="text" name="phone" maxlength="12" size="45" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['phone'])) echo $_POST['phone']; ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="email" class="formText">Email Address:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="45" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                        <textarea id="myTextArea" rows="4" cols="37" name="comments" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['comments'])) echo $_POST['comments']; ?>"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="checkbox">
                        I agree to all of the terms set 
                        out in the <span class="italics">Permission To <br />
                        Use / Reproduce</span> conditions on 
                        the left side of this page.</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input  type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Agreed">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>                      
</div>
</div>
<?php
    require 'bottomInclude.php';
?>
```

Comment: When you call `mail()` what is the response from the SMTP server?

Comment: Can you try switching the gmail address to another one? Gmail has some issues with emails sent from PHP - they often end up in spam, if they're not discarded silently. See if it works with a Yahoo / Hotmail / etc one.

Comment: @andrewsi: I've tried it with three different email addresses: Gmail, Hotmail, and our work email.

Comment: @keicea - OK. Then the next step is to check the return value from `mail()`. When you call `mail()` what does it return?

Comment: @David: I'm not sure. I don't have access to the server. I give the files to our IT department and they upload them.

Comment: @andrewsi: I'm not sure. I don't have access to the server. I've spoken with IT and they said they have no idea why it isn't working, either. I'll see if they will tell me what the response/return is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mail() can be a difficult one to test. First you should check whether the function is returning true or false. If it is returning true then it is being sent, but its possible the email is getting caught in a spam blocker along the way and never gets to the recipient. I had this happen on one of my sites where we sent warning emails to an admin with the domain in the subject. The hosting company's anti-spam marked our domain name as a spam keyword and no emails would go out if they contained the domain name anywhere in them.

I also read somewhere that the from address has to be a real email address. I have sent emails from an address that didn't exist but might not always work.